# Stripe PaymentElement intermittently not displaying

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm having a problem with Stripe's PaymentElement react component.  It displays correctly but only sometimes.  After doing multiple reloads/restarts of the entire react app, and multiple CTRL+F5, the form intermittently doesn't display.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the times when it displays correctly nor the times when it fails to display.

When the modal displays, correct display of the payment form including PaymentElement component looks like this:
[image]

When the PaymentElement fails to display, there are two possible appearances.  Either it shows the form fields with nothing in them:
[image]

Or the entire iFrame is empty, no fields or labels or any HTML content within the body.
[image]

I followed [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) to integrate the Elements and PaymentElements components into my react app.

Initially I was developing using public and secret keys issued to a free trial account.  It was hoped that switching to paid might make a difference, but now that I'm using paid keys I'm getting the same intermittent results with the PaymentElement sometimes not displaying.

I keep comparing my code to the docs and can't find what I've missed.  As per the docs, the stripe promise is instantiated outside the component's rendering.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DynamicTextArea from './components/DynamicTextArea';
import MultiSelect from "./components/MultiSelect";
import CheckoutForm from './components/CheckoutForm';
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_xxxxxxxx");


function App() {
```

Payment intent is created with useEffect and an emtpy array so it triggers after page load.  This react app is backed by a REST API (.NET6) which handles the calls to Stripe and returns the client secret.

```
const createPaymentIntent = () => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("/payments/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "product001" }] }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
}

const showPaymentForm = async () => {
    setPaymentModalOptions({...paymentModalOptions, visible: true});
}

useEffect(() => {
    createPaymentIntent();
}, []);
```

Options to pass to the PaymentElement component, which is wrapped in a CheckoutForm component as per the docs:

```
const options = {
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    appearance: {
        theme: 'stripe',
    }
};
```

The Stripe Elements component is wrapped in a bootstrap modal.  To be clear, the modal always displays correctly, but intermittently the PaymentElement within the modal does not display.

```
    <div id="payment-modal" className={`modal ${paymentModalOptions.visible ? 'modal-show' : ''}`} role="dialog">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-body">
                    {clientSecret && (
                        <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
                            <CheckoutForm onPaymentSucceeded={handlePaymentSucceeded} onCancelPayment={handlePaymentCancelled}/>
                        </Elements>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lastly, the CheckouForm component where the PaymentElement actually resides.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

import './CheckoutForm.css';

export default function CheckoutForm(props) {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [paymentIsLoading, setPaymentIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs"
  }

  const delay = async (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

  const handleSubmit = async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    setPaymentIsLoading(true);

    const paymentResult = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: "http://localhost:44472",
      },
      redirect: 'if_required'
    });
    
    if (paymentResult.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      setMessage("Payment successful!");
      
      // wait two seconds, then close the payment modal
      await delay(2000);
      props.onPaymentSucceeded();
      
    } else {
      setMessage("Payment unsuccessful");
    }

    setPaymentIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={paymentElementOptions} />
          <div id="payment-buttons-wrapper">
              <div className="payment-button-group">
                  {paymentIsLoading ?
                      <div className="spinner-border text-secondary" id="payment-spinner" role="status"></div>
                      : <button disabled={paymentIsLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit" className="btn btn-light border">
                          <span id="button-text">Pay now</span>
                        </button>
                  }
              </div>
              
              <button onClick={props.onCancelPayment} className="btn btn-light border">Cancel</button>
          </div>
      
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

I've seen intermittent rendering problems in React before and its often caused because of a pending response to an async call, or failing to use useEffect() correctly (I've done it multiple times).  In this case I don't see where I'm going wrong.  Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
This error appears in the console intermittently.  The error sometimes appears even when the PaymentElement displays correctly.  Other times the error doesn't appear even though the Payment Element fails to display.  I'm not convinced they are connected.
[image]

UPDATE: I have reached out to Stripe support on this.  In the meantime I'm sharing an additional screenshot.  Sometimes when the form fails to display, there's an iFrame present in the page that contains the full payment form, but apparently the iFrame has opacity: 0.  This is not a full explanation for the problems I'm having because sometimes the iFrame's body tag is literally empty, so it wouldn't matter whether it was invisible or not.  But in this example, the iFrame is fully loaded with the Stripe Payment form, it's just invisible due to the opacity.  I some point in the loading process I'm guessing the Stripe components are responsible for changing this property so the form displays, and that process is being interrupted before it gets there.  Cause is still unknown.
[image]

The other failure state results in an empty root div within the iFrame's html body.  In this failure state, as with the previous one shown above, there are no errors in the console.
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in your Dev Console when it doesn't render or renders incorrectly? Do you have strict-mode (https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled by chance? If so, that can oftentimes cause issues here and I'd recommend disabling that.

Comment: @bismarck Thanks for asking, I forgot to post the console error initially.  I've updated the original post.  The error is also intermittent.  Sometimes this error appears even though the PaymentElement displays correctly, and other times the error does not appear even when the Payment Element fails to display.  So I have trouble saying they are even related.  I'm looking into the strict mode....

Comment: Hmm that isn't really definitive enough. The first error may have something to do with it though not very informative. The second one ("Failed to retrieve dependencies") is a known No-Op stemming from Google currently. I think your next best bet here is to write into Stripe Support with somewhere that Support can access your page (using ngrok for example if you are developing locally) so that someone can take a deeper look. It is going to be very hard to debug this here.

Comment: I searched the code base for StrictMode and came up with 0 results.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm using plain java script and have the same issue of intermittently not displaying. When it doesn't display i get an error in the browsers console `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to select session. Make sure Elements is initialized with clientSecret or use the nullableSessionSelector() instead.`. I initialize the elements only using the appearance object to collects address, then use `elements.update({ mode: 'payment', amount: orderTotal, currency: 'usd', });` to allow me to create a Payment Element without an intent.